# Negate multiple words

Tags: regex, perl

**Test String:**

```
${$var1} bla ${$var2} bla ${$var2}
\${$var2} bla \\\${$var2} bla $var1
\\${$var1} bla \\${$var2} bla \${$var2}
\\\{$var2} bla \\${$var2} bla \${$var2}
$var1 bla \$var1 bla \\$var1 bla \\\$var1
\$var1 bla \\$var1 bla \\\$var1
\\$var1 bla \\\$var1 bla \$var1 bla
\\\$var1 bla \\$var1 bla \\\$var1
```

**Selection I'm looking for:**

I'm looking for a regex to select only `${$varN}, \\${$varN}, $varN, \\$varN`
without selecting `\${$varN}, \\\${$varN}, \$varN, \\\$varN`

**Regex I've tried:**
`(\$\{\$\w*\})|(\$\w*)` but it selects all `${$varN}` and `$varN`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail where your string comes from and why you're only trying to match the words with an even number of backslashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\|{)(?:\\\\)*\$(?:{\$)?\w*}?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/7)

**RegEx Description:**

- `(?<!\\|{)` - Negative lookahead to assert we don't have backslash or `{` as previous character
- `(?:\\\\)*` - match 0 or more **pairs** of backslashes
- `\$` - Match a literal `$`
- `(?:{\$)?` - Match *optional* `{` followed by `$`
- `\w+` - Match 1 or more words
- `}?`- Match *optional* closing `}`

---

**Update:** If you want more precise matching (one that disallows `${$var3`) then use this advanced PCRE regex that uses `if-else-then` construct:

```
(?<!\\|{)(?:\\\\)*\$({\$)?\w+(?(1)})
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/8)

Comment: Quick explanation will be appreciated, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot .. regex101 explains :)

Comment: I've also added detailed explanation in my answer.